# A closed subset of a locally connected space is locally connected?

Tags: general-topology

A closed subset of a locally connected space is locally connected?

A closed subset of a locally path-connected space is locally path-connected?

Is there any counter-example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbb R$ is locally connected and locally path-connected. The Cantor set is a closed subset of $\mathbb R$ which is not locally connected at any of its points. For a simpler example, take $\{0\}\cup\{\frac1n:n\in\mathbb N\}$; however this example is locally connected at some of its points.

Comment: Why $\{0\} \cup \{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is not locally connected or not locally path connected?

Comment: It is not locally connected at $0$.

Answer (score 2):

$\Bbb{R}^2$ is locally path connected and locally connected. There is a standard example of a closed subset $X \subset\Bbb{R}^2$ which is neither locally connected, nor locally path-connected: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve

Answer (score 2):

consider $\mathbb{R^2}$...if you wish for a connected closed subset which does not follow two properties...then cosider comb space http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_space as a subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$

Comment: ohhh...I was stupid